# Till used for a point of time

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I think till is used to show a length of time and perfect tense shows a time period but the past indefinite a point of time, but in the following sentence

He did not see her till a few days ago.

The past indefinite is  used. Is it correct?

Comment: I don't think ***until, till, 'til*** are exactly used to show a *length* of time. They're used to identify an ***end point** in time.* In your example, this means the end of the period during which he didn't see her (a period of unspecified length, since we don't know when it started). I don't know what you mean by "past indefinite" (it looks like Simple Past to me), but your cited text is fine. He saw her a few days ago, having *not* seen her prior to that (for some time, or *never* before; that aspect is ambiguous).

Comment: If I say he had not seen her till a few days ago

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: "He did not see her till a few days ago" is fine.  I personally would say, "He did not see her until a few days ago."  For me, this flows better.